# Problems parsing date like twitter

Tags: javascript, parsing, date, twitter

I'm parsing tweets from twitter and I want to show dates like twitter "posted 40 minutes ago", "posted 1 hour ago" but I have the following problem:

When I get user tweets, twitter give me this format (link json):

```
http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/BarackObama.json?count=5&callback=308
"created_at": "Tue Jul 03 01:54:48 +0000 2012",
```

When I search a hashtag this one:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&rpp=5&q=%23wasabi
"created_at": "Thu, 05 Jul 2012 14:31:57 +0000",
```

Can anyone help me parse these dates?

Comment: What have you tried?  `var date = new Date(data.created_at)` works fines for both date formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Resig has a nice little date parsing script too.
http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/

Here's a JSFiddle with the code you need.

Updated with example tweet grabbing - you know you want my answer ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/ETACy/4/

Answer (score 5):

this should work:

```
new Date(data.created_at);
```

(you can use [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) too - http://jsfiddle.net/ZhF6y/)

Comment: but.. please more code.. I dont get this, I try with time ago but I must to convert the date and I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert to the Unix timestamp, try out [Livestamp.js](http://mattbradley.github.com/livestampjs/). It's unobtrusive and auto-updating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but you don't need an external library, you just need to put UTC in front of the + sign.

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse(tweet.created_at.replace(/( \+)/, ' UTC$1')));
```

Inspired by https://gist.github.com/ghostrocket/799429