# Best way to compare dates for most recent in JS?

Tags: javascript, parsing, date, twitter

I'm talking about ones encoded in the format in which the twitter API returns its dates, like...

`"Tue Jan 12 21:33:28 +0000 2010"`

The best thing I thought of was to try to slice it up with regexes to become something more like...

`20100112213328`,

but there's *got* to be a better way.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/141504/1358004

Comment: I've noticed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346741/problems-parsing-date-like-twitter) although it isn't exactly what I want.

Comment: I'm just looking to compare them....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript Date will correctly parse the Twitter date :

```
  var d1 = new Date ("Tue Jan 12 21:33:28 +0000 2010")
    , d2 = new Date ("Tue Jan 12 22:33:28 +0000 2010");
```

The you can compare these using the getTime method which converts to numeric form:

```
  if (d1.getTime() < d2.getTime())
  {
       //...
  }
```

Or, simply

```
if (d1 < d2)
{
}
```

If needs must, explicitly coerce to number:

```
if (+(d1) < +(d2))
{
}
```

Comment: the `>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=` operators automatically coerce a Date object to numbers, as does `+(dateObject)`... your `if` statement is incorrect BTW: you're missing a closing `)`, and it'll always return true if d1 != 0:

Answer (score 1):

You can just make a new Date object using a string like `"Tue Jan 12 21:33:28 +0000 2010"`.

```
var dateString = "Tue Jan 12 21:33:28 +0000 2010";
var twitterDate = new Date(dateString);
```

Then, you can simply use < and > to make comparisons.

```
var now = new Date();
if (now < twitterDate) {
    // the date is in the future
}
```

Comment: woah!! Is it specified anywhere how those work? Or is it "specifically unspecified," like `localeCompare()`?

Comment: I found this with a little googling: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date What specifically did you want to know?

Comment: /me heads off to read it, waiting to be able to accept yr answer.

Comment: @adlwalrus: The JS date object can be tricky at first [but here's some more details on the matter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007379/what-makes-new-date-1000-a-valid-javascript/12007624#12007624), though I have to make a couple edits to be 100% accurate)

Comment: @evan doesn't seem to mention the comparison operators.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are you asking about < and > ?

Comment: @adlwalrus: not directly, I've edited it just now, so that it does, but it basically deals with how JS deals with a date object in comparisons, and arithmic operations. more specifically: in combination with the overloaded `+` operator (addition and string concatenation) and the equality operators. All of that stuff _and_ how the Date objects differ from other objects

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, that was a great link! Tha nks.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285441/how-does-js-date-comparison-work/

Answer (score 0):

As far as the ECMAScript specification 5.1 goes (see 15.9.1.15), the only supported string interchange format for date-times is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` (along with shorter forms).

Otherwise (15.9.4.2):

> If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.

I would use the regular expression based solution which is short and guaranteed to work anywhere; relying on the user's browser and localization parameters seems a little eerie to me.