# How does JS date comparison work?

Tags: javascript, date, comparison

Let's assume I have a proper `Date` object constructed from the string: `"Tue Jan 12 21:33:28 +0000 2010"`.

```
var dateString = "Tue Jan 12 21:33:28 +0000 2010";
var twitterDate = new Date(dateString);
```

Then I use the `<` and `>` *less than* and *greater than* comparison operators to see if it's more or less recent than a similarly constructed `Date`.  Is the algorithm for comparing dates using those operators specified, or is it *specifically unspecified*, like `localeCompare`?  In other words, am I guaranteed to get a more recent date, this way?

```
var now = new Date();
if (now < twitterDate) {
    // the date is in the future
}
```

Comment: Yes you will get most recent date this way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Relational operations](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) on objects in ECMAScript rely on the internal [ToPrimitive](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1)  function (with hint number) that you can access, when it is defined, using [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf).

Try

```
var val = new Date().valueOf();
```

You'll get the internal value of the date which is, as in many languages, the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970 UTC (the same that you would get using `getTime()`).

This means that you're, by design, ensured to always have the date comparison correctly working.

[This article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/Object-to-Primitive-Conversions-in-JavaScript) will give you more details about `toPrimitive` (but nothing relative to comparison).

Answer (score 1):

I think yes. Using `if (now < twitterDate)`, it evaluates to `if (now.valueOf()<twitterDate.valueOf())`. `valueOf()` delivers the number of milliseconds passed since 01/01/1970 00:00:00, so the comparison of those 2 numbers is valid.

check it like this

```
var then = new Date("Tue Jan 12 21:33:28 +0000 2010")
   ,now  = new Date;

console.log(then.valueOf(),'::',now.valueOf(),'::',now<then);
  //=> 1263332008000 :: 1352365105901 :: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Date values in Javascript are numbers, as stated in the [ECMA Script specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1). So the Date values are compared as numbers.

This is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pUASN/) of your code (I set twitterDate in the future).

```
(function(){
    var dateString = "Tue Jan 12 21:33:28 +0000 2014";
    var twitterDate = new Date(dateString);

    var now = new Date();
    if (now < twitterDate) {
         document.write('twitterDate is in the future');
    }
    else
    {
        document.write('twitterDate is NOT in the future');
    }

})()​
```