# Comparison of object and number in JS

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

How this piece of code works without giving an error?

```
function waitThreeSeconds() {
     var ms = 3000 + new Date().getTime();
     while (new Date() < ms) {}
     console.log('Finished function');
}
```

I mean, in while loop, object is comparing to number. I read about Date and getTime() and I couldn't find if there is type conversion between object and number in above code. Maybe new Date() uses miliseconds, but converts to string when it is about to be displayed on screen?

Comment: why not take `setTimeout`?

Comment: See [How does JS date comparison work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13285441/4642212). It’s not exactly about comparing dates to _numbers_, but the concept is the same.